# Setting htmlunit webclient browser version doesn't work

Tags: java, spring-boot, web-scraping, htmlunit

I am using htmlunit 2.19 (version update didn't solve this problem). I want to **scrape** a web page which is dynamically generated in javascript. After setting browser version in webclient, webpage still returns message that browser version is unsupported. All the sample codes and examples I have seen do the same as I do, but work perfectly.

Do I have to consider any other details in this matter ?

Here is my htmlunit maven dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
        <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
        <version>2.19</version>
    </dependency>
```

and sample code :

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
        webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
        webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
        webClient.setCssErrorHandler(new SilentCssErrorHandler());
        webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
        webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage(url);
```

Comment: HtmlUnit is now at version 2.39.0. Please update to this latest version. If the problem persists, please prepare a simple sample containing the real url to give me a chance to reproduce and open an issue at github.

Comment: I've already tried 2.38.0 and 2.39 and getting following error :   Error loading JavaScript from [https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id=GTM-W685H8R].

org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to www.googletagmanager.com:443 [www.googletagmanager.com/216.58.207.72] failed: Connection timed out: connect

Comment: Connection timed out - looks like a network problem - you are behind a proxy?

Comment: No, I am not. I have also set ProxyAutoConfigUrl, but I am still getting the same error. The interesting thing is, after these errors I am still getting default html, but it is after several errors and 30-40 seconds.

Comment: That's it,  I've checked my netstat established connections and as it seems I am behind a proxy server. The connection error has been solved, thank you. Now I have a error during a javascript execution. I will have a look at it, and open a new question thread if I can't resolve it.